# array - list format input

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have the following question: how can I change the format of `curve2` (list). I want something similar to `curve`

```
curve = [0.0556, 0.0563]
curve2 = [[0.0159, 0.0178]]
```

Context: I´d like to apply a certain code, but I don´t get the result I expect since the input has different format

My code is something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

curve = [0.0556, 0.0563]
curve2 = [[0.0159, 0.0178]]


df= pd.DataFrame()
def SUM (curve):
    df['COl1'] = curve
    return df

print(SUM(curve))
```

PD: `curve2` is a row extracted from an array (as a list):

```
[[ 0.01593353  0.01783041]
 [ 0.00917833  0.00593893]
 [ 0.00829569  0.02123637]
 [-0.03057529 -0.04138836]
 [ 0.05212978  0.03239212]]
```

Comment: Not sure I get your question, but `curve2[0]`?

Comment: `curve2.ravel()` ?

Comment: @RafaelC Ravel seems to work. According to google it is similar to reshape right? Thanks